# Exposing parameters in dependent cmdlets as script parameters

Tags: powershell

Take for example the optional parameter `-Filter` on `Get-ChildItem`.

If one were to incorporate a call to `Get-ChildItem` in a PowerShell script, how can `-Filter` be exposed also as an optional parameter on the script such that it will only be passed to the cmdlet if specified?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) to splat the relevant parameters of your script to `Get-ChildItem`:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$Path,
  [Parameter()]
  [psobject]$NonGetChildItemParam
  [Parameter()]
  [string]$Filter
)

if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("NonGetChildItemParam"))
{
    $PSBoundParameters.Remove("NonGetChildItemParam")
}

Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the script an optional parameter `-Filter` and pass its argument through to `Get-ChildItem`.

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Path,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [scriptblock]$Filter
)

if ($Filter) {
  Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $Filter
} else {
  Get-ChildItem $Path
}
```